# Select block of code in stackblitz on chrome mobile on android

Tags: stackblitz

How do I select block of code in stackblitz on chrome mobile on android?

Long press brings up menu with cut/copy/paste/ for that line but I need to select a block of code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to use the Command palette.

1. Touch start of code to move cursor there
2. Long press to bring up menu
3. Select command palette
4. Set selection anchor
5. Move cursor to end of code
6. Steps 2 and 3 again
7. Select from anchor to cursor